# Bull job is not stalled when processor terminated only when getting back up

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, bull

*the code that I'm talking about is the repro code linked below*

---

I have 2 "states" in the code (both of them are listening to queue global events):

1. Add a single message
2. Listen to messages

For some reason, Bull job is not reported as *stalled* when the listener worker is terminated only when the worker is back up.

although it should as stated in the docs:

> ```js
> .on('stalled', function (job) {
>   // A job has been marked as stalled. This is useful for debugging job
>   // workers that crash or pause the event loop.
> });
> ```
>
> From [Bull event reference](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/REFERENCE.md#events) in `.on('stallled', ...)` event handler

[GitHub Repro](https://github.com/rluvaton/bull-ui-stalled-no-recevied-when-exit) (it contains `docker-compose` and everything set up with explanation)

---

**Edit:**

Tested on [bullmq](https://github.com/taskforcesh/bullmq) and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am afraid this works as designed, since in Bull the workers are also responsible of detecting stalled jobs, while in BullMQ you have the QueueScheduler that takes care of this.

From [Bull Repo - Issue 2141](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/2141)